# Php foreach loop to populate country list dropbox

Tags: php, select, foreach

Whats wrong here?

```
require("countrylist.php"); //array 
echo "Your country:<br /><select name=\"country\">";
foreach($countryList as $key => $value)
{ 
echo "<option value=" . $key . ">";
echo $value . "</option>";
} 
echo "</select>";
```

Working on local xampp server with php 5.4 installed but not working online(5.2),
i don't get it. I get an empty dropbox.

The array:

```
$countryList = array (
'AD' => 'Andorra',
'AE' => 'United Arab Emirates',
'AF' => 'Afghanistan' ....
```

and so on.

Comment: Hi, "not working" is not a good error description. What happens exactly?

Comment: Hello  => I get an empty dropbox on live site, thanks.

Comment: Well, what does `$countrylist` contain? `print_r($countryList)`

Comment: print_r() gives no errors.

Comment: Well, does it output the array data? What does the final generated HTML look like?

Comment: It output the array data, i get an empty select box.

Comment: What does the final generated HTML look like?

Comment: I solved my problem, it was a js problem. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Turn error reporting on your live server for this page only, or create yourself a conditional message if the include file is not found.

```
if(! require("countrylist.php") ){

echo 'Oops, cannot find the file in ' . ini_get("include_path");

}else{

var_dump($countryList);

}
```

Comment: I can print the array so theres no include errors, it works on my local xampp, not online. ty

Answer (score 0):

Ensure CountryList.php has the proper

> < ?php

tag at the top of the file so that the parser knows it's PHP. (Note there should be no space between the < and ? but Stack Overflow protects against embedded PHP in the comments.